# How to programmatically resize an UIButton to the text size and keep a nice padding?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have a button that is created dynamically and needs to be resized. It has plenty of space where to grow but calling sizeToFit seams to do nothing or at least not enlarging the button enough.

How can I obtain the desired effect?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `NSString` method `-sizeWithFont:`. It returns a `CGSize` that will inform you as to how much size your text will need in the button. Then you can adjust the button's frame based on this size, adding whatever padding you desire to the width and height of the button's frame. Something like this:

```
NSString *msg = @"The button label";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
CGSize msgSize = [msg sizeWithFont:font];
CGRect frame = button.frame;
frame.size.width = msg.size.width+10;
frame.size.height = msg.size.height+10;
button.frame = frame;
```

(written from memory; not compiled. :-)

Of course, you have to set the button title and font as well...

Comment: Am I wrong or the hardcoding of the padding is not recommended. I think that iOS have some constant for these.

Comment: This is just an example. You can add some padding, or not, as you choose. And yes, you can use some constant defined elsewhere, if you like. Sometimes that makes a lot of sense, if you're using a constant value in a lot of places: rather than hard code it everywhere, define a constant so that later, if you have to change the value, you change one place. Yeah, that's a best practice, for sure. But you should use a healthy dose of common sense too. Defining a constant for EVERY value you might otherwise hardcode is overkill. :-)

Comment: CGFrame isn't available in iOS5.0 . i tried but it gives error . please advisee

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must have typed this from memory. Of course, it should be `CGRect`, not CGFrame, which doesn't exist on any platform! I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, sizeWithFont: is depreciated. Now you should use sizeWithAttribute:.

But that's not how I would solve this issue.  There are two ways you can go about it:

1) To use [button sizeToFit] make sure AutoLayout is disabled.  Otherwise, you won't be able to adjust the size of your button programmatically.  You'll have to adjust the size of your constraints.

2) However, this answer is very limited in is use. In the example I'm about to show you, the button would go off the screen because the text is all on one line.  To change the height of your button while constraining the width use the following code.  **Once again make sure autolayout is turned off or this will not work.**

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0];
    NSString *text = @"This is a very long new title for the button to be sure, now I'm going to add even more";

    [self.testButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.testButton.titleLabel.font = font;

    CGFloat width = self.testButton.frame.size.width - 10;  //button width - padding width
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    size.height = ceilf(size.height);
    size.width = ceilf(size.width);
    self.testButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.testButton.frame.origin.x, self.testButton.frame.origin.y, self.testButton.frame.size.width, size.height + 15);
```

Because boundingRectWithSize will pass you a rect that has non-integer sizes you have to use ceilf to round up.

I subtract 10 from the width before I pass it into boundingRectWithSize to create padding for my button.